# Problems about `slice` and `append` in Go

Tags: go

I have written the following code. But I can't have it compiled. Here is my code:

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    tmp := make([]int, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        tmp[i] = i
    }
    res := mapx(foo, tmp)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", res)
}

func foo(a int) int {
    return a + 10
}

func mapx(functionx func(int) int, list []int) (res []int) {
    res = make([]int, 10)
    for _, i := range(list) {
        append(res, functionx(i))
    }
    return
}
```

Meanwhile the error message is also very confusing:
`prog.go:21: append(res, functionx(i)) not used`

But if I replace `append(res, functionx(i))`(line 21) with `res = append(res, functionx(i))`, it works quite well. Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> [Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)
>
> The variadic function append appends zero or more values x to s of
>   type S, which must be a slice type, and returns the resulting slice,
>   also of type S.
>
> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large slice that fits both the
>   existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned
>   slice may refer to a different underlying array.
>
> [Calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.

In Go, arguments are passed by value.

You need to write `res = append(res, functionx(i))` so that you don't discard the new value for res, which refers to a different slice and, possibly, a different underlying array.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    res := []int{0, 1}
    fmt.Println(res)
    _ = append(res, 2) // discard
    fmt.Println(res)
    res = append(res, 2) // keep
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

Output:

```
[0 1]
[0 1]
[0 1 2]
```